# Error in server-running while acessing web-page

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, server

We are assigned to write a simple app including three pages + mainpage that is going to have links to all other pages (content cut for the version here). Below is fully-functional code, that accomplishes all of that. Nevertheless there is an error randomly arising while running server, which, however, does not affect the work of the server at all.

I have tried to look at what is going on with the requests sent to the server and it showed me that periodically instead of one request, server receives two

```
import socketserver
from server import ThreadedTcpServer
from request import Request
from response import Response

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print('Connected from: ' + str(self.client_address))
        print('==========Request===========')
        request = Request(self.rfile)
        print(request.request_line + '\n')

        response = Response(self.wfile)
        response.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        response.add_header('Connection', 'close')
        if request.path == '/':
        ...

        response.send()

ThreadedTcpServer.allow_reuse_address = True

server = ThreadedTcpServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
server.serve_forever()
server.server_close()
```

In the log of the server I expect to see only request_lines and print of connection info,but sometimes instead of one request it shows two from different client_addresses and two arising exceptions like:

```
Connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 34962)
==========Request===========
GET /three HTTP/1.1

Connected from: ('127.0.0.1', 34966)
==========Request===========
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 34966)
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 34962)
```

and huge traceback starting from socketserver module and ending up in my request class where it cannot parse request_line.